# wrong custom design user/authorities in spring security

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, jpa, spring-security

I think there is a weakness in my user and authorities design. The login works fine but I have a `org.hibernate.TransientPropertyValueException` on my create_user page.

When I add a new user from a form, with this code :

```
public fr.cnamts.navigo.domain.User create(UserCreateForm form) {
    fr.cnamts.navigo.domain.User user = new fr.cnamts.navigo.domain.User();
    user.setUsername(form.getEmail());
    user.setPassword(new BCryptPasswordEncoder().encode(form.getPassword()));
    user.setEnabled(true);

    Authorities role = new Authorities();
    role.setUser(user);
    role.setAuthority(form.getRole());

    role = authoritiesRepository.save(role);
    user.addAuthorities(role);

    user = userRepository.save(user);
    return user;
}
```

There is a `org.hibernate.TransientPropertyValueException` on `save(role)`.
Authorities class :

```
@Entity
@Table(name="authorities", uniqueConstraints = @UniqueConstraint(
        columnNames = { "authority", "username" }))
public class Authorities {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    @Column(name = "authority_id", 
    unique = true, nullable = false)
    private Integer id;

    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinColumn(name = "username", nullable = false)
    private User user;

    @Column(name = "authority", nullable = false, length = 45)
    private String authority;

    public Authorities() {
    }

    public Authorities(User user, String role) {
        this.user = user;
        this.authority = role;
    } 

    public void setUser(User user) {
        this.user = user;
        if (!user.getAuthorities().contains(this)) { // warning this may cause performance issues if you have a large data set since this operation is O(n)
            user.getAuthorities().add(this);
        }
    } // assume other basic getters and setters
```

Users one :

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "users")
public class User {
    @Id
    @Column(name = "username", nullable = false, unique = true, length = 60)
    private String username;

    @Column(name = "password", nullable = false, length = 60)
    private String password;

    @Column(name = "enabled", nullable = false)
    private boolean enabled;

    // private boolean tokenExpired;

    @OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, mappedBy = "user")
    private Set<Authorities> authorities;

    public User() {
        this.authorities = new HashSet<Authorities>();
    }

    public User(String username, String password, boolean enabled) {
        this.username = username;
        this.password = password;
        this.enabled = enabled;
        this.authorities = new HashSet<Authorities>();
    }

    public User(String username, String password, boolean enabled,
            Set<Authorities> userRoles) {
        this.username = username;
        this.password = password;
        this.enabled = enabled;
        if (userRoles != null) {
            this.authorities = userRoles;
        } else {
            this.authorities = new HashSet<Authorities>();
        }
    }

    public void addAuthorities(Authorities role) {
        this.authorities.add(role);
        if (role.getUser() != this) {
            role.setUser(this);
        }
    }

    public void addAuthorities(String role, User user) {
        this.addAuthorities(new Authorities(user, role));
    }
```

When I add a new user, I need the user's roles/authorities, but to create the authorities object, I need the user instance.

Here is an extract of the console trace :

```
Hibernate: select user0_.username as username1_1_, user0_.enabled as enabled2_1_, user0_.password as password3_1_ from users user0_ where user0_.username=?
Hibernate: select nextval ('hibernate_sequence')
Hibernate: select user_.username, user_.enabled as enabled2_1_, user_.password as password3_1_ from users user_ where user_.username=?
2015-12-15 16:21:26.390  WARN 6832 --- [nio-8081-exec-3] o.h.a.i.UnresolvedEntityInsertActions    : HHH000437: Attempting to save one or more entities that have a non-nullable association with an unsaved transient entity. The unsaved transient entity must be saved in an operation prior to saving these dependent entities.
    Unsaved transient entity: ([fr.cnamts.navigo.domain.User#datm.flux1@cnamts.fr])
    Dependent entities: ([[fr.cnamts.navigo.domain.Authorities#4]])
    Non-nullable association(s): ([fr.cnamts.navigo.domain.Authorities.user])
2015-12-15 16:21:26.398 ERROR 6832 --- [nio-8081-exec-3] o.a.c.c.C.[.[.[/].[dispatcherServlet]    : Servlet.service() for servlet [dispatcherServlet] in context with path [] threw exception [Request processing failed; nested exception is org.springframework.dao.InvalidDataAccessApiUsageException: org.hibernate.TransientPropertyValueException: Not-null property references a transient value - transient instance must be saved before current operation : fr.cnamts.navigo.domain.Authorities.user -> fr.cnamts.navigo.domain.User; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalStateException: org.hibernate.TransientPropertyValueException: Not-null property references a transient value - transient instance must be saved before current operation : fr.cnamts.navigo.domain.Authorities.user -> fr.cnamts.navigo.domain.User] with root cause

org.hibernate.TransientPropertyValueException: Not-null property references a transient value - transient instance must be saved before current operation : fr.cnamts.navigo.domain.Authorities.user -> fr.cnamts.navigo.domain.User
    at org.hibernate.action.internal.UnresolvedEntityInsertActions.checkNoUnresolvedActionsAfterOperation(UnresolvedEntityInsertActions.java:137) ~[hibernate-core-4.3.11.Final.jar:4.3.11.Final]
```

I think I'm missing something on the getter/setter side or the constructor side. The objects on the database side seem good. Here is the creation code (postgresql) :

```
create table users ( 
    username varchar(50) primary key,
    password varchar(255) not null,
    enabled boolean not null DEFAULT TRUE
);


create table authorities (
    authority_id SERIAL,
    username varchar(50) not null,
    authority varchar(50) not null,
    PRIMARY KEY (authority_id),
    CONSTRAINT uni_username_authority UNIQUE(authority,username),  
    constraint fk_roles_users foreign key (username) references users (username)
);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As the authorities table has a Foreign Key to the users table then User has to be saved before Authority.

You can have Hibernate persist the associated User before persisting the Authority by adding the cascade annotation to the association:

```
@ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
@JoinColumn(name = "username", nullable = false)
private User user;
```

https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/5/api/javax/persistence/ManyToOne.html